# How to multiply all odd numbers between 50 and 100 in python

Tags: python

I'm new to to python and tried a lot to solve this but can't get this right.
I need help on this
Thank you
The code I wrote is -

```python
prod=1
for i on range (50,100,2):
    prod = prod*i
    print(prod)
```

Answer (score 1):

change `for i in range(50,100,2):` to `for i in range(51,100,2):`

Comment: oh im sorry i made a mistake in writing the code here its prod*i

Comment: i want that but the answer is wrong..

Comment: I've edited the answer. Is the correct value returned now?

Comment: the answer its printing is 46639050149927205077041204760231563385360671875 and correct answer should be 7477801851840180387532660695884489880609375

Comment: this code will output the product of the list of odd numbers from 51 inclusive to 99 inclusive. i.e. [51,53,...99].

Your expected value is something different, check with that again that you are calculating the correct expected value.

Comment: @AkshatJain Your number is wrong. Your number has only twice the prime factor 11, but it should appear three times in the product (55, 77, 99). alexandros solution is correct.